# Trying to get local IP address in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

does anyone know how I can get my proper local ip address instead of the default virtualbox 10.0.etc ive tried changing the settings to briding adaptor it doesnt work i need my proper ip address to use metasploit and other tools in kali PLEASE HELP

Comment: thanks for getting back to me ;) yeah ive tried that it doesnt work I still get the Default IP when I ifconfig plus when I ping it, it says host unreachable Ive tried dirrernt network adaptors and still wont work Im using a TP-LINK Archer T2u AC 600 atm any suggestions?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the VM change the network adapter to Bridged mode, then re-start your VM this should be able to give your VM an IP from the Host series.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me ;) yeah ive tried that it doesnt work I still get the Default IP when I ifconfig plus when I ping it, it says host unreachable Ive tried dirrernt network adaptors and still wont work Im using a TP-LINK Archer T2u AC 600 atm any suggestions?? :)